# How to generate a combination of two numbers that equal a given input

Tags: python, combinations

I am trying to generate a combination of two numbers using only 5 and 7 that will equal the sum of any given input. The input range is 24:1000. What I've done so far is determine if the input is divisible by 5 or 7 and then generate a list whose sum equals the input.
Here is my working example:

```
def change(amount):
    if amount not in range(24,1001):
       print("The number is outside the range.")
    else:
       remainder=amount%5
    if remainder==0:
       n = int(amount/5)
       array=[0 for i in range(n)]
       for i in range(n):
       array[i]=5
       return array, sum(array)
    else:
       remainder=amount%7
    if remainder==0:
       n = int(amount/7)
       array=[0 for i in range(n)]
       for i in range(n):
       array[i]=7
       return array, sum(array)
    else: 
     # here is where am stuck       
print(change(28))
```

The output needs to be in the form of an array. For example: for change(24), the array should be [5,5,7,7].

Answer (score 2):

Most simplistic approach I could think of

```
def change(target):
    if target not in range(24,1001):
           raise ValueError("The number is outside the range.")
    res = []
    while target % 5 != 0:
        res.append(7)
        target -= 7

    while target != 0:
        res.append(5)
        target -= 5

    return res


change(28)
>>> [7, 7, 7, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loops for this, just a little bit of algebra. See the comments for details.

```
def change(amount):
    if not 24 <= amount <= 1000:
       print("The number is outside the range.")
       return None

    # 5*3 - 7*2 = 1, so 5*(3*n) + 7*(-2*n) = n, and therefore
    # 5*(3*n - 7*k) + 7*(5*k - 2*n) = n for all k
    # We want to find a small k so that the terms in each bracket are positive
    k = 3 * amount // 7
    x = 3 * amount - 7 * k
    y = 5 * k - 2 * amount
    return x, y, [5] * x + [7] * y

# Print the sequences for some small amounts
for i in range(24, 70):
    x, y, seq = change(i)
    print(i, x, y, sum(seq) == i)

# Check all values in the range
for i in range(24, 1001):
    x, y, seq = change(i)
    assert sum(seq) == i
print('ok')
```

**output**

```
24 2 2 True
25 5 0 True
26 1 3 True
27 4 1 True
28 0 4 True
29 3 2 True
30 6 0 True
31 2 3 True
32 5 1 True
33 1 4 True
34 4 2 True
35 0 5 True
36 3 3 True
37 6 1 True
38 2 4 True
39 5 2 True
40 1 5 True
41 4 3 True
42 0 6 True
43 3 4 True
44 6 2 True
45 2 5 True
46 5 3 True
47 1 6 True
48 4 4 True
49 0 7 True
50 3 5 True
51 6 3 True
52 2 6 True
53 5 4 True
54 1 7 True
55 4 5 True
56 0 8 True
57 3 6 True
58 6 4 True
59 2 7 True
60 5 5 True
61 1 8 True
62 4 6 True
63 0 9 True
64 3 7 True
65 6 5 True
66 2 8 True
67 5 6 True
68 1 9 True
69 4 7 True
ok
```

This doesn't *necessarily* give the shortest sequence for every amount, but it's usually close to the optimum, and it's not too hard to modify this code to get the optimum. But that will be left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

To learn more about this technique, please see the Wikipedia article on linear [Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation).

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest I could think of, as it only uses a single `while` cycle.

```
def change(amount):
    if not 24 <= amount <= 1001:
        print('{} is outside range'.format(amount))
        return
    sevens = []
    fives, remainder = divmod(amount, 5)
    while remainder:
        amount -= 7
        sevens.append(7)
        fives, remainder = divmod(amount, 5)
    return [5] * fives + sevens
```

PS: please don't mix tabulations sizes :-)

Answer (score 0):

For all combinations here is an idea. The loops can be optimise further

```
import itertools


def change(target):
    nums = [5, 7]
    min_len = int(target / 7)
    max_len = int(target / 5) + 1

    res = []
    for len_ in range(min_len, max_len):
        r = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(nums, len_)
        for item in r:
            if sum(item) == target:
                res.append(item)

    return res
```

And a little bit optimised one. Collect all combinations within the possible range and filter out the ones with sum == target.

```
import itertools


def change(target):
    nums = [5, 7]
    min_len = int(target / 7)
    max_len = int(target / 5) + 1

    res = []
    for len_ in range(min_len, max_len):
        res += (list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(nums, len_)))

    return list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == target, res))
```

The output which contains all possible combinations for target = 70

```
[(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), (5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), (5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)]
```

Without any loop in FP style. Reducing all possible combinations into one list and filter the correct elements of this list in return.

```
import itertools
from functools import reduce


def change(target):
    nums = [5, 7]
    min_len = int(target / 7)
    max_len = int(target / 5) + 1

    res = reduce(lambda x, y: 
                 x + (list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(nums, y))),
                 range(min_len, max_len), [])


    return list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == target, res))
```